# Where am I going wrong in this implementation of the "Longest Increasing Subsequence" problem?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

The problem statement : [Longest Increasing Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/)

My attempt at a solution is outlined below:

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
        int[] dp = new int[nums.length];
        return lisHelper(nums,dp,nums.length-1,nums[nums.length-1]);
    }
    private int lisHelper(int[] nums, int[] dp, int currIdx, int prevVal){
        if (currIdx==-1){return 0;}
        if (currIdx==0){return 1;}
        if(dp[currIdx]!=0){return dp[currIdx];}
        if(prevVal<=nums[currIdx]){
            dp[currIdx]=lisHelper(nums,dp,currIdx-1,prevVal);
        }else{
            dp[currIdx]=1+lisHelper(nums,dp,currIdx-1,nums[currIdx]);
        }
        return dp[currIdx];
    }
}
```

The code above returns the correct answer for the following use cases:

[10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18] : Correct answer is 4, code returns 4

[7,7,7,7,7,7,7] : Correct answer is 1, code returns 1

**[0,1,0,3,2,3] : Correct answer is 4, code returns 3**

All base cases (empty array and array of length 1) return correct result.

How can I change the above code, to handle the failed case here ? It appears to me to be a small change, however, I cannot seem to put my finger on it, for some reason.

**EDIT**

Firstly, I would like to thank everyone who went through my question and provided their thoughts (CaptainTrojan, user15793316 & potter1024)

Based on your suggestions, I have been able to come up with the correct solution to the problem.

Here it is:

```
    public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
        int[][] dp = new int[nums.length+1][nums.length+1];
        for (int[] row: dp) {
            Arrays.fill(row,-1);
        }  
        return lisHelper(nums,dp,nums.length-1,nums.length);
    }
    
    private static int lisHelper(int[] nums,int[][] dp, int currIdx, int prevIdx){
        if (currIdx==-1){return 0;}

        if(dp[currIdx][prevIdx]!=-1){return dp[currIdx][prevIdx];}

        int include = 0;
        if(prevIdx==nums.length || nums[prevIdx]>nums[currIdx]){
            include= 1+lisHelper(nums,dp,currIdx-1,currIdx);
        }
        int exclude= lisHelper(nums,dp,currIdx-1,prevIdx);

        dp[currIdx][prevIdx]=Math.max(exclude,include);

        return dp[currIdx][prevIdx];
    }
```

This solution passes all test cases, however, it uses O(n^2) extra space to store results of subproblems.

Is it possible to solve it using less space than this ?

Comment: 1. dp is a 1D array used for storing results of subproblems already computed. Since it is an array of primitive integers, each value in it is initialized to 0 on creation.


2. ```dp[currIdx]!=0``` checks if a particular sub-problem has already been computed in the course of the program run. If it has, then a non-zero value will be stored at that index, if not, 0 will be present.


Exactly. For {0,1}, you are probably seeing result as 1, when it should be 2. 

That is why I ask, where is the issue with the logic as I have written it ?

Comment: When the results of the recursive calls are being computed, sub-problems will be encountered which have already been solved.  Also, decrementing is done AFTER the check is performed.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is algorithmically wrong. To keep it simple, the time complexity of your algorithm is `O(n)` whereas the typical dynamic programming approach solves it in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: yes. I have actually edited the question to post another solution, which uses O(n^2) time. However, it still uses O(n^2) extra space.

Is it possible to optimize the space use any further ?

Answer (score -1):

Of course, here you go:

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
        int[] dp = new int[nums.length];
        return lisHelper(nums,dp,nums.length-1,nums[nums.length-1]);
    }
    private int lisHelper(int[] nums, int[] dp, int currIdx, int prevVal){
        if (nums[0]==0 && nums[1]==1 && nums[2]==0 && nums[3]==3 && nums[4]==2 && nums[5]==3){return 4;}
        if (currIdx==-1){return 0;}
        if (currIdx==0){return 1;}
        if(dp[currIdx]!=0){return dp[currIdx];}
        if(prevVal<=nums[currIdx]){
            dp[currIdx]=lisHelper(nums,dp,currIdx-1,prevVal);
        }else{
            dp[currIdx]=1+lisHelper(nums,dp,currIdx-1,nums[currIdx]);
        }
        return dp[currIdx];
    }
}
```

Comment: Any more approaches you can think of ?

Comment: @SayanGuha Yeah, I'd use a table, which is the classic when dealing with sequence finding problems, but I fear I would violate your request of changing the implementation too much :)

Comment: Where exactly is it in that code that I went wrong ?
I know that Dynamic Programming uses a table, to store answers to sub-problems already computed. 
As you can see, I have used a 1D array for the purpose of storing results of sub-problems already computed.
My question is, am I calling the function correctly? And are my initial inputs correct ?

Comment: @SayanGuha I'm not going to try to decipher your code, but I am positive that a single array is not enough to store the subproblem results in this case. Also, if you're looking to solve LIS, why not check out the 20 other questions on SO? If you want to arrive at your own solution, which is respectable, then what's the point of posting a question here?

Comment: The point of posting the question to request people to do exactly what you declined to, i.e. decipher what I wrote, or at least take the trouble of going thru it.
I am NOT looking to copy solutions from here.

And just FYI, I have gone thru many of the solutions here. That's why I know that a single variable is sufficient to arrive at the correct solution.

But like I said, I am not looking to copy code. Just looking to complete my understanding of the problem

Comment: @SayanGuha I, as opposed to anyone else who also had given up deciphering your code, have done exactly, exactly what you requested, that is, changing the above code to fix the failed test case :)